# Configure the CXF Service in resources.groovy using the DSL instead of resource.xml

Tags: grails, cxf

I was successfully created cxf wsdl web-services in grails. Now i want configure cxf simple front end endpoint.

I was successfully configure cxf endpoint in  resource.xml file in grails project.

Like..

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:simple="http://cxf.apache.org/simple"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/simple http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/simple.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <!--create CXF service-->
<simple:server serviceClass="com.j2.signup.FaxSignupService" address="/FaxSignupService">

</simple:server>
</beans>
```

But i want same cxf endpoint configuration in resource.groovy DSL file instead of creating new resource.xml.

Anybody have idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `importBeans` in place of the `<import>` elements

```
importBeans('classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml')
```

and for the `<simple:server>` you can duplicate this directly in the DSL (see "using Spring namespaces" at the end of [this section of the user guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/guide/spring.html#theBeanBuilderDSLExplained))

```
xmlns simple:'http://cxf.apache.org/simple'
simple.server(serviceClass:"com.j2.signup.FaxSignupService",
              address:"/FaxSignupService")
```

If your `FaxSignupService` class itself needs dependencies injecting by Spring then you need to declare it as a top-level bean too

```
faxSignupService(com.j2.signup.FaxSignupService) { bean ->
  bean.autowire = "byName"
}
xmlns simple:'http://cxf.apache.org/simple'
simple.server(serviceClass:"com.j2.signup.FaxSignupService",
              serviceBean:"#faxSignupService",
              address:"/FaxSignupService")
```

(NB if `FaxSignupService` is a genuine Grails service under `grails-app/services` then it is already registered as a bean by default and the extra bean definition is not required, just adding the `serviceBean:'#faxSignupService'` to the `simple.server` is enough.)

Comment: Thank you so much  Ian, It's working fine. Thanks for given reply in short time.

Comment: Hello Ian, it's working fine. But I am getting null value for **def dataSource** in com.j2.signup.FaxSignupService. i want to use grails dataSource service for fetching data from db. You have any idea about this?

Comment: @ChiragDasani I've added some more detail regarding this case.